# Helm on AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Having my cluster up and running on AWS EKS, I'm finding trouble running `helm init` with the following error:

```
$ helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade
Error: error installing: deployments.extensions is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create deployments.extensions in the namespace "kube-system"
```

`kubectl` works properly (object retrieval, creation and cluster administration), authenticating and authorizing correctly by running `heptio-authenticator-aws` at connection time ( with an `exec` section in the kubectl config).

In order to prepare the cluster for helm, I created the service account and role binding as specified in the helm [docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md).

I've heard of people having helm running on EKS, and I'm guessing they're skipping the `exec` section of the kubectl config by hardcoding the token... I'd like to avoid that!

Any ideas on how to fix this? My guess is that it is related to helm not being able to execute `heptio-authenticator-aws` properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was running `helm` version 2.8.2 when obtaining this error, upgrading to v2.9.1 fixed this!

Comment: I also had issue on EKS, upgrading helm to 2.9.1 resolved it.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I'm mad I spent so much time troubleshooting this but happy it was this easy.